# Looking for a good javascript player that can do playlists and has advertising support

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, media, ads

I am looking for a javascript player that is opensource and has support for video and audio playlists and has support for advertising (or at least a way to disable the controls while the ad is playing). I also need callbacks for when a song on the playlist ends, when the player starts to play, and a method to switch the play-lists.

I've looked into jwplayer and don't want to use that because its not free for ad support and I've tried jwplayer but there is no way to effectively have ads with it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about jPlayer (now JW Player):  http://jplayer.org/

- Free and open source.
- Playlists: http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-video/
- Callbacks (events): http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-events

Comment: unfortunately jplayer doesn't have a way to disable its controls

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Kaltura?

http://www.kaltura.org/project/HTML5_Video_Player

Comment: I've looked into it, no support for playlists

Comment: Um, can't you just do that writing some javascript that listens for playback events and changes the source when the end of the current video has been reached?  It isn't necessarily the player that has to support playlists, but rather you might be required to write code to add playlists support to a current player?

Comment: You're right, although then I'd be looking at 2 players (because kaltura doesnt support audio). After asking this I've found j mediaelement: http://protofunc.com/jme/  It doesnt have too much out of the box but it does have a lot of scripting functionality. I havent played with it enough yet to see if disabling the controls will be vaible